# Redirecting all requests through HTTPS in a way that works with both public and private IPs

Tags: apache-2.2, https, httpd.conf

I want to force Apache to redirect all traffic through HTTPS:

```
# Redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mypublicip/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Unfortunately, this does not work when I am trying to access my website from my local network using my Web server's private IP. How could I work around this limitation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) supports more variables like `%{HTTPS}`. For your requirement `%{HTTP_HOST}` is the way to go.

Comment: Do you mean something like `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]`?